# Intercept JSON before returning from web.api

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I am looking to intercept the returning model from my web.api and run the returning data through a translation service, i.e. Google or Azure for languages other than English.  Is there way to add an attribute or additional config to intercept the model, perform the translation, and then return back to the controller?

Comment: Are you looking at ActionFilter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#action-filters
You can have your code to be executed either before or after your action methods are executed

Comment: ActionFilter, as @Ashish said, for Asp Net Mvc, and middleware for asp net core. But be careful, you can't translate the json properties, only string / numeric values... Before using a translate service you must parse the data you want to translate... This kind of interception can drastically affect your API response performance. Be aware: sounds like a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

try this code also add this code

//add this line global.asax file

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomLogHandler());

public class CustomLogHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var logMetadata = await BuildRequestMetadata(request);
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        logMetadata = await BuildResponseMetadata(logMetadata, response);
        await SendToLog(logMetadata);
        return response;
    }
    private async Task<LogMetadata> BuildRequestMetadata(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        LogMetadata log = new LogMetadata
        {
            RequestMethod = request.Method.Method,
            RequestTimestamp = DateTime.Now,
            RequestUri = request.RequestUri.ToString(),
            RequestContent = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(),
        };
        return log;
    }
    private async Task<LogMetadata> BuildResponseMetadata(LogMetadata logMetadata, HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        logMetadata.ResponseStatusCode = response.StatusCode;
        logMetadata.ResponseTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
        logMetadata.ResponseContentType = response.Content == null ? string.Empty : response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
        logMetadata.Response = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return logMetadata;
    }
    private async Task<bool> SendToLog(LogMetadata logMetadata)
    {
        try
        {
         //write this code
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```